# How to split a string after the nth character in r

Tags: r, string, split, data-management

I am working with the following data:

```
District <- c("AR01", "AZ03", "AZ05", "AZ08", "CA01", "CA05", "CA11", "CA16", "CA18", "CA21")
```

I want to split the string **after the second character** and put them into two columns.

So that the data looks like this:

```
state  district
AR        01
AZ        03
AZ        05
AZ        08
CA        01
CA        05
CA        11
CA        16
CA        18
CA        21
```

Is there a simple code to get this done? Thanks so much for you help

Comment: have you looked at `substr`?

Comment: I have not. I'm more familiar with  ```strsplit()```. But since there is nothing to split on, its not applicable in this case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `substr` if you always want to split by the second character.

```
District <- c("AR01", "AZ03", "AZ05", "AZ08", "CA01", "CA05", "CA11", "CA16", "CA18", "CA21")
#split district  starting at the first and ending at the second
state <- substr(District,1,2)
#split district starting at the 3rd and ending at the 4th
district <- substr(District,3,4)
#put in data frame if needed.
st_dt <- data.frame(state = state, district = district, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you for the code and for the annotation.

Answer (score 5):

you could use `strcapture` from base R:

```
 strcapture("(\\w{2})(\\w{2})",District,
                    data.frame(state = character(),District = character()))
   state District
1     AR       01
2     AZ       03
3     AZ       05
4     AZ       08
5     CA       01
6     CA       05
7     CA       11
8     CA       16
9     CA       18
10    CA       21
```

where `\\w{2}` means two words

Answer (score 4):

The OP has [written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60084046/how-to-split-a-string-after-the-nth-character-in-r#comment106266179_60084046)

> I'm more familiar with `strsplit()`. But since there is nothing to split
>   on, its not applicable in this case

*Au contraire!* There is something to split on and it's called *lookbehind*:

```
strsplit(District, "(?<=[A-Z]{2})", perl = TRUE)
```

The lookbehind works like "*inserting an invisible break*" after 2 capital letters and splits the strings there.

The result is a list of vectors

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "AR" "01"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "AZ" "03"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "AZ" "05"
>
> [[4]]
> [1] "AZ" "08"
>
> [[5]]
> [1] "CA" "01"
>
> [[6]]
> [1] "CA" "05"
>
> [[7]]
> [1] "CA" "11"
>
> [[8]]
> [1] "CA" "16"
>
> [[9]]
> [1] "CA" "18"
>
> [[10]]
> [1] "CA" "21"
> ```

which can be turned into a matrix, e.g., by

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(District, "(?<=[A-Z]{2})", perl = TRUE))
```

> ```
>       [,1] [,2]
>  [1,] "AR" "01"
>  [2,] "AZ" "03"
>  [3,] "AZ" "05"
>  [4,] "AZ" "08"
>  [5,] "CA" "01"
>  [6,] "CA" "05"
>  [7,] "CA" "11"
>  [8,] "CA" "16"
>  [9,] "CA" "18"
> [10,] "CA" "21"
> ```

Comment: Thank you for providing this.  This faciliates efficiently splitting a large table of strings using `tstrsplit` in data.table

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_match` to capture first two characters and the remaining string in separate columns.

```
stringr::str_match(District, "(..)(.*)")[, -1]

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "AR" "01"
# [2,] "AZ" "03"
# [3,] "AZ" "05"
# [4,] "AZ" "08"
# [5,] "CA" "01"
# [6,] "CA" "05"
# [7,] "CA" "11"
# [8,] "CA" "16"
# [9,] "CA" "18"
#[10,] "CA" "21"
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `tidyverse` this is very easy using the function `separate` from `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
District %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  separate(value, c("state", "district"), sep = "(?<=[A-Z]{2})")

# A tibble: 10 × 2
   state district
   <chr> <chr>   
 1 AR    01      
 2 AZ    03      
 3 AZ    05      
 4 AZ    08      
 5 CA    01      
 6 CA    05      
 7 CA    11      
 8 CA    16      
 9 CA    18      
10 CA    21
```

Answer (score 0):

Treat it as fixed width file, and import:

```
# read fixed width file
read.fwf(textConnection(District), widths = c(2, 2), colClasses = "character")
#    V1 V2
# 1  AR 01
# 2  AZ 03
# 3  AZ 05
# 4  AZ 08
# 5  CA 01
# 6  CA 05
# 7  CA 11
# 8  CA 16
# 9  CA 18
# 10 CA 21
```